# How to transform my simple input into input group bootstrap with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

It is possible to transform my simply input into a input-group bootstrap like this with jquery:

[image: input]

To create this input i use:

```
<div class='input-group date' id='ff'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control" name="end_date" id="ed" required      placeholder="Select date"/>
  <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span>
</div>
```

I need to transform the input cause it has been generated before and it is simply input with and id

Comment: Do you mean that at the start you wil have simple `<input/>` and you want to make input-group for this element with jQuery?

Comment: Exactly, this is what i need, it is possible?

Comment: yes, sure, give me few minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example in [**jSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nicolai8/phZ9g/1):

**HTML:**

```
<input type='text' class="form-control" name="end_date" id="ed" required="" placeholder="Select date" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var $input = $("#ed");
var $inputGroup=$("<div/>").addClass("input-group date").attr("id","ff");
$inputGroup.append($input.clone());
$inputGroup.append("<span class='input-group-addon add-on'><span class='fa fa-calendar'></span></span>");
$input.replaceWith($inputGroup);
```

But I don't like the html in javascript code, I prefer using templates like **[unserscore.js template](http://underscorejs.org/#template)**. In that case code will be like the following:

**HTML:**

```
<input type='text' class="form-control" name="end_date" id="ed" required="" placeholder="Select date" />
<script type="text/template" id="inputGroupTemplate">
  <div class='input-group date' id='<%=divId%>'>
    <%=inputHTML%>
    <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="<%=iconClass%>"></span></span>
  </div>
</script>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var template= _.template($("#inputGroupTemplate").html());
var $input = $("#ed");
$input.replaceWith(template({divId:"ff",iconClass:"fa fa-calendar",inputHTML:$input.clone()}));
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have a standard input to start with like:

```
    <input type="text" id="ed" />
```

You can use jQuery to manipulate the DOM like so:

```
    var txtbox = $("#ed"); //target your input
    txtbox.wrap( "<div class='input-group date' id='ff'></div>" ); //wrap it with input group
    txtbox.after("<span class='input-group-addon add-on'><span class='fa fa-calendar'></span></span>"); //add spans after the input
    //then specify attributes of the text field
    txtbox.addClass("form-control");
    txtbox.attr("name", "end_date").attr("placeholder", "Select date");
    txtbox.prop("required", true);
```